# Need to change port for document opening in Compodoc

Tags: documentation, compodoc

I am using Compo-doc for documenting my Angular 2 application. After successful creation of documentation folder in directory structure of my application, when I am trying to access the Document on browser through the command, by default it opens on "localhost:8080" port.
We are already using 8080 port for Micro-services. So I need to change the port for documentation Rendering.
Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the Compodoc website, under the *usage* section (https://compodoc.github.io/website/guides/usage.html) you will find different commands to customise your application, generally using the command:

`compodoc <src> [options]`

and in your case "*Change default serving port*", it should have as value for *src* and *option* respectively:

```
-r, --port [port]
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Compodoc is great documenttion tool for you angular applications, here is the documentation link for the same 
https://compodoc.app/guides/usage.html

From the above list:

`compodoc -s -r 9000`

should work for you (replace 9000 to the port you want).

`-s, --serve`        Serve generated documentation

`-r, --port [port]`  Change default serving port